# Don't understand sscanf_s behaviour

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, scanf

This behaviour seems to have changed between Visual Studio 2012 and 2015.

```
int i,j;

sscanf_s("1†3", "%d†%d", &i, &j);
```

In the above code j is not being set. I think this is possibly because † is not an ASCII char. The above does set j if † is replaced by a space. However, the code worked fine in Visual Studio 2012.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Edit:

I worked around this by using swscanf_s instead. I suppose it was a fluke that the above worked in Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: file encoding? what's the byte sequence?

Comment: Have you checked the vendor's bugtracking system or reported the issue there? A regression between two versions is surely worth a bug ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug:  the narrow character scanf format string parser has trouble matching literal characters with negative values.  There is an active bug for this on Microsoft Connect:  [Problems with sscanf](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Feedback/Details/2281034).  This will be fixed in the next update to the Universal CRT used by Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10.